# Push data to Campaign Monitor using Python

Tags: python, api, amazon-redshift, campaign-monitor

Campaign Monitor is a service where we can send emails to a set of subscribers. We can create multiple lists within Campaign Monitor and add the required users to these lists as subscribers(to whom we can send personalised emails). So, here I am trying to send a set of customers' details like their name, emails, total_bookings, and first_booking to the campaign monitor's list using the API in Python so that I can send emails to this set of users.
More details on campaign monitor: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/api/v3-3/subscribers/

I am new to using Campaign Monitor. I have searched documentation, a lot of posts and blogs for examples on how to push data with multiple custom fields to Campaign Monitor using Python. By default, a list in Campaign Monitor will have a name and an email that can be added, but I want to add other details for each subscriber(here I want to add total_bookings and first_booking data) and Campaign Monitor provides custom fields to achieve this.

For instance:

I have my data stored in a redshift table named `customer_details` with the fields name, email, total_bookings, first_booking. I was able to retrieve this data from redshift table using Python with the following code.

```
# Get the data from the above table:
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from customer_details")

creator_details = cursor.fetchall()
# Now I have the data as a list of sets in creator_details
```

Now I want to push this data to a list in the Campaign Monitor using API like `request.put('https://api.createsend.com/api/../.../..')`. But I am not sure on how to do this. Can someone please help me here.

Comment: explain it to us like we know nothing about campaign monitor ... from my quick googling you add a subscriber to a list with this endpoint https://www.campaignmonitor.com/api/v3-3/subscribers/

Comment: @JoranBeasley Thank you for your comment, I updated the question with details. I went through the link you provided. I understood there is a method we can use to do this, but I am not sure how the API can be used to send the above-mentioned data. I tried the following by iterating over each customer record but received a 400 response:
```requests.put('https://api.createsend.com/api/v3.3/subscribers/{my_list_id}.json?email={customer_email}', auth=requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth(MY_API_KEY, ''), json = {'CustomFields': [{'key':'total_bookings', 'value':customer_details[2]}])```

Comment: attempted to answer ... again i dont have a token so i cant really test, and even if i did i wouldnt want to necessarilly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

400 indicated invalid parameters

we can first see the request is POST not PUT

so first change `requests.put` to `requests.post`

the next thing is that all the variables need to be sent either as www-formdata or as json body data not sure which

and lastly you almost certainly cannot verify with basic auth ... but maybe

something like the following

```
some_variables = some_values
...
header = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {MY_API_KEY}"}
data = {"email":customer_email,"CustomFields":[{"key":"total_bookings","value":customer_details2}]}
url = f'https://api.createsend.com/api/v3.3/subscribers/{my_list_id}.json'
res = requests.post(url,json=data,headers=header)
print(res.status_code)
try:
   print(res.json())
except:
   print(res.content)
```

after looking more into the API docs it looks like this is the expected request

```
{
    "EmailAddress": "subscriber@example.com",
    "Name": "New Subscriber",
    "MobileNumber": "+5012398752",
    "CustomFields": [
        {
            "Key": "website",
            "Value": "http://example.com"
        },
        {
            "Key": "interests",
            "Value": "magic"
        },
        {
            "Key": "interests",
            "Value": "romantic walks"
        }
    ],
    "Resubscribe": true,
    "RestartSubscriptionBasedAutoresponders": true,
    "ConsentToTrack":"Yes"
}
```

which we can see has `"EmailAddress"` not `"email"` so you would need to do

```
data = {"EmailAddress":customer_email,"CustomFields":[{"key":"total_bookings","value":customer_details2}]}
```

Im not sure if all of the fields are required or not ... so you may also need to provide `"Name","MobileNumber",Resubscribe",etc`

and looking at "Getting Started" it looks like the publish a python package to make interfacing simpler

http://campaignmonitor.github.io/createsend-python/

which makes it as easy as

```
import createsend
cli = createsend.CreateSend({"api_key":MY_API_KEY})
cli.subscriber.add(list_id,"user@email.com","John Doe",custom_fields,True,"No")
```

(which I found here https://github.com/campaignmonitor/createsend-python/blob/master/test/test_subscriber.py#L70)